# Sync files from Amazon S3 to local

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nfs

I have a Amazon S3 bucket with multiple directories. These directories contain all sorts of important files.

I want to backup my S3 bucket and save it to a nas-server here at my local network. I have written a bash script which runs once every day.

The scripts most important part is this:

```
sudo aws s3 sync s3://$s3bucket/$s3folder $localpath --size-only>> $LOG_DIR/$LOG_FILE
```

I am certain that all variables are set and correct.
The files are copied to the right locations, but for one subfolder I get this error:

```
warning: Skipping file /fullPathToLocalLocation/bucket/subfolder. File/Directory is not readable.
```

The permissions for this folder are exactly the same for this folder as for the other subfolders.

When I execute this command:

```
ls -l
```

I get this error:

And when I compare the output of:

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

with the output of:

```
ls -1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

the result is different(309774 vs. 309772)
The console also displays the error:

```
ls: reading directory .: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I've also checked the output of

```
dmesg | tail
```

and it had this error:

```
[11823.884616] NFS: directory bucket/subfolder contains a readdir loop.Please contact your server vendor.  The file: randomfilename.pdf has duplicate cookie 124416205
```

I've deleted the file with the duplicate cookie from my nas and retried the sync between my s3 bucket and my local nas, this time it worked.
But the second time I tried it displayed the same error as before.

Is it possible that I have 2 times the same file on s3, one time with the extension in uppercase and one time with the extension in lower case, and this causes the issue?

Every time this sync error occurs, it redownloads the whole subfolder from S3 and does not just sync it. I only noticed this after a couple of days after it already downloaded 2 Tb from Amazon by continuously overriding the files on my local nas. Because of this, I received a very high bill from Amazon.

Has anyone else experienced an issue like this or knows a way to solve this?
An obvious solution might be to delete the files which are causing this issue from S3 itself, but I can't seem to be able to list more than one file for each filename using command line tools for S3 or cyberduck. 
Maybe they only show one file when there are multiple with the same name.

Thank you for reading this till the end.

Comment: Are you running these commands on your NAS, or on a machine that has mounted a share from your NAS? If the latter, try the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be running in to this issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46671

It's a problem with NFS, not AWS. Try running your sync script directly on the NAS to see if that resolves the problem.

Apparently this problem has been fixed with ext4 on newer Linux kernels - you might be able to update your NAS to pick up this fix.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Both the NAS and the server which runs the script should be updated to the latest stable version.
I've retried the sync and the same error occurred.
I would really like this script to run on this server and not on the NAS, I would also have to install the aws tools in order to execute this script on the NAS.

Comment: Did you try running it on the NAS to verify that is indeed the cause? The AWS tools are easy to install, as long as your NAS supports Python/pip.

Comment: If it works from the NAS, it confirms the issue is the one I linked. In that case, you need to find an alternative to NFS - maybe SMB?

Comment: I seem to have problems with installing software on my NAS, I was following this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-pip And I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pkgutil
ImportError: No module named pkgutil

After I execute this command: python get-pip.py
The model of the NAS is: QNAP TS459U+

Comment: Sounds like your QNAP is missing some of the Python requirements. Try installing pip according to some QNAP-specific instructions, then do "pip install awscli". http://gleenders.blogspot.nl/2014/04/install-python-pip-on-qnap-nas.html

Comment: I've noticed my nas has a build in S3 sync function. I've tried this and it caused the whole directory to be downloaded again, each time it is executed. After some trail and error I've managed to install awscli on my nas. When I execute the sync command there, it is working without any problems. 

I'm going to accept this answer as correct, but do you have any suggestions of how I could still run this command on my other server? 
Maybe adjust the script so the aws sync command is called over ssh?

Comment: Yes, you could execute awscli over SSH. I think in this case I would write a script that is saved on server NAS, then on the other server set up a cron job that calls this script via SSH. Would that give you everything you need?

Comment: It would, thank you for your help! I've just received an email from Qnap support:"After some discussions with the head office it is determined that this is a bug of the QNAP 

we do not have a workaround for this issue yet but our department working on the matter "